# constant truncated to integer error during type conversion of float constant to int

Tags: go, type-conversion, constants

The following code is raising the error  "**Constant truncated to integer** " on the line "**var a int = int(1.333)**".I am new to GO and not able to figure out the actual problem.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    var x, y int = 3, 4
    const k float64=2.2
    var a int = int(1.333)
    var f float64 = math.Sqrt(float64(x*x+y*y))
    var z uint = uint(f)
    fmt.Println(x, y, z,a)
}
```

Comment: The `int` type can only be used for whole numbers (also called "integers") such as `1`, `5`, `600`, etc.  It can't be used for a fraction (that is, anything with a dot in it) such as `1.333`. You will need to use `float32` or `float64` for that. It's not clear from the code why you want `a` to be an `int` (you're only printing it, and not doing anything else with it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conversion of constants follows different rules than the conversion of non-constants.

First non-constants:

> Conversions between numeric types
>
> For the conversion of non-constant numeric values, the following rules
>   apply:
>
> 1. ...
> 2. **When converting a floating-point number to an integer, the fraction is discarded (truncation towards zero).**
> 3. ...

So this is possible:

```
var f = float64(1.333)
var i = int(f)
```

---

Now constants:

> A constant value x can be converted to type T if x is **representable** by
>   a value of T.

Then, in the documentation, there's a list of example expressions, one of them being this:

```
int(1.2) // illegal: 1.2 cannot be represented as an int
```

On representability

> A constant x is representable by a value of type T if one of the
>   following conditions applies:
>
> - x is in the set of values determined by T.
> - T is a floating-point type and x can be rounded to T's precision without overflow. Rounding uses IEEE 754 round-to-even rules but with an IEEE negative zero further simplified to an unsigned zero. Note that constant values never result in an IEEE negative zero, NaN, or infinity.
> - T is a complex type, and x's components real(x) and imag(x) are representable by values of T's component type (float32 or float64).

None of the 3 conditions applies to the expression `var a int = int(1.333)` and therefore it is illegal.

---

Read more about [Conversions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) and [Representability](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Representability)